# Javascript Hide/Show div not working on input searchBar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having trouble running javascript hide/show div using CSS classes, the initial state all the divs are hidden than when i type in the searchBar the name of the recipe (like the div ribs) it show only the ribs div and so far is working, but when i clear the searchBar its show all the div instead of hiding all of them again.

HTML

```
<section class="recipe section" id="work">
            <h2 class="section__title">Recipe</h2>
            <div class="recipe__filters">
                <input type="text" onkeyup="search_recipe()" placeholder="search" id="search" class="section__search"></input>
                <div class="cat">
                    <h3>Categories</h3>
                    <i class="uil uil-arrow-right" id="categories-button"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="hide_categories" id="h_categories">
                    <span class="all recipe__item active-recipe " data-filter='all'>All </span>
                    <span class="recipe__item" data-filter='.breakfast'>Breakfast</span>
                    <span class="recipe__item" data-filter='.dessert'>dessert</span>
                    <span class="recipe__item" data-filter='.burgersandwiches'>Burger & Sandwiches</span>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="recipe__container container">
                <!-- <div class="recipe__card mix ">
                    <img src="./asset/img" alt="" class="recipe__img">
                    <h3 class="recipe-title-item"></h3>
                    <a href="#" class="recipe__button">
                        More details <i class='uil uil-angle-right-b recipe__icon'></i> 
                    </a>
                </div> -->
                <div class="recipe__card mix">
                    <img src="./asset/img/ramen_recipe.jpeg" alt="" class="recipe__img">
                    <h3 class="recipe-title-item">Helllllllo</h3>
                    <a href="#" class="blog__button">
                        More details <i class='uil uil-angle-right-b blog__icon'></i> 
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="recipe__card mix">
                    <img src="./asset/img/burrito_recipe.jpeg" alt="" class="recipe__img">
                    <h3 class="recipe-title-item">aelllllllo</h3>
                    <a href="#" class="blog__button">
                        More details <i class='uil uil-angle-right-b blog__icon'></i> 
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="recipe__card mix">
                    <img src="./asset/img/pasta_recipe.jpeg" alt="" class="recipe__img">
                    <h3 class="recipe-title-item">Telllllllo</h3>
                    <a href="#" class="blog__button">
                        More details <i class='uil uil-angle-right-b blog__icon'></i> 
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="recipe__card mix burgersandwiches">
                    <img src="./asset/img/burger_recipe.jpeg" alt="" class="recipe__img">
                    <h3 class="recipe-title-item">Telllllllo</h3>
                    <a href="#" class="blog__button">
                        More details <i class='uil uil-angle-right-b blog__icon'></i> 
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="recipe__card mix">
                    <img src="./asset/img/chips_recipe.jpeg" alt="" class="recipe__img">
                    <h3 class="recipe-title-item">Telllllllo</h3>
                    <a href="#" class="blog__button">
                        More details <i class='uil uil-angle-right-b blog__icon'></i> 
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="recipe__card mix ">
                    <img src="./asset/img/raspberry_brownies_recipe.jpeg" alt="" class="recipe__img">
                    <h3 class="recipe-title-item">Telllllllo</h3>
                    <a href="#" class="blog__button">
                        More details <i class='uil uil-angle-right-b blog__icon'></i> 
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="recipe__card mix ">
                    <img src="./asset/img/steaks_recipe.jpeg" alt="" class="recipe__img">
                    <h3 class="recipe-title-item">Zelllllllo</h3>
                    <a href="#" class="blog__button">
                        More details <i class='uil uil-angle-right-b blog__icon'></i> 
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="recipe__card mix ">
                    <img src="./asset/img/shrimp_pasta_recipe.jpeg" alt="" class="recipe__img">
                    <h3 class="recipe-title-item">Telllllllo</h3>
                    <a href="#" class="blog__button">
                        More details <i class='uil uil-angle-right-b blog__icon'></i> 
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="recipe__card mix ">
                    <img src="./asset/img/ribs_recipe.jpeg" alt="" class="recipe__img">
                    <h3 class="recipe-title-item">Ribs</h3>
                    <a href="#" class="blog__button">
                        More details <i class='uil uil-angle-right-b blog__icon'></i> 
                    </a>
                </div>

        </section>
```

CSS

```
.recipe__container {
    padding-top: 1rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 3rem;
}

.recipe__filters {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    column-gap: .75rem;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.recipe__item {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: var(--title-color);
    padding: .25rem .75rem;
    font-weight: var(--font-medium);
    border-radius: .5rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.recipe__items {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: var(--title-color);
    font-weight: var(--font-medium);
    border-radius: .5rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.recipe__card {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 32px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37);
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    display: none;
}

.recipe__img {
    border-radius: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: var(--mb-1-25);
    width: 230px;
}

.recipe-title-item {
    font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
    font-weight: var(--font-medium);
    margin-bottom: var(--mb-0-75);
}

.hide_categories {
    display: none;
    transition: all ease-in-out;
}

.categories {
    display: grid;
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
    transition: all ease-in-out;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, max-content);
}

#categories-button {
    z-index: 9;
}

.cat {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

#categories-button {
    margin-left: 1rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.active-recipe {
    background-color: var(--first-color);
    color: var(--white-color);
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
textarea[type="text"],
select {
    padding-left: 1rem;
}

.recipe {
    display: block;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function search_recipe() {
    let input = document.getElementById('search').value
    input = input.toLowerCase();
    let recipeCard = document.getElementsByClassName('recipe__card');

    for (i = 0; i < recipeCard.length; i++) {

        if (recipeCard[i].textContent.toLowerCase().includes(input)) {
            recipeCard[i].style.display = "block";
        } else {
            recipeCard[i].style.display = "none";

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function search_recipe() {
    let input = document.getElementById('search').value
    input = input.toLowerCase();
    let recipeCard = document.getElementsByClassName('recipe__card');

    for (i = 0; i < recipeCard.length; i++) {

        if (input != "" && recipeCard[i].textContent.toLowerCase().includes(input)) {
            recipeCard[i].style.display = "block";
        } else {
            recipeCard[i].style.display = "none";
        }

    }
}
```

```css
.recipe__container {
    padding-top: 1rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 3rem;
}

.recipe__filters {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    column-gap: .75rem;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.recipe__item {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: var(--title-color);
    padding: .25rem .75rem;
    font-weight: var(--font-medium);
    border-radius: .5rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.recipe__items {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: var(--title-color);
    font-weight: var(--font-medium);
    border-radius: .5rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.recipe__card {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 32px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37);
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    display: none;
}

.recipe__img {
    border-radius: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: var(--mb-1-25);
    width: 230px;
}
```

```html
<section class="recipe section" id="work">
            <h2 class="section__title">Recipe</h2>
            <div class="recipe__filters">
                <input type="text" onkeyup="search_recipe()" placeholder="search" id="search" class="section__search"></input>
                <div class="cat">
                    <h3>Categories</h3>
                    <i class="uil uil-arrow-right" id="categories-button"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="hide_categories" id="h_categories">
                    <span class="all recipe__item active-recipe " data-filter='all'>All </span>
                    <span class="recipe__item" data-filter='.breakfast'>Breakfast</span>
                    <span class="recipe__item" data-filter='.dessert'>dessert</span>
                    <span class="recipe__item" data-filter='.burgersandwiches'>Burger & Sandwiches</span>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="recipe__container container">
                <!-- <div class="recipe__card mix ">
                    <img src="./asset/img" alt="" class="recipe__img">
                    <h3 class="recipe-title-item"></h3>
                    <a href="#" class="recipe__button">
                        More details <i class='uil uil-angle-right-b recipe__icon'></i> 
                    </a>
                </div> -->
                <div class="recipe__card mix">
                    <img src="./asset/img/ramen_recipe.jpeg" alt="" class="recipe__img">
                    <h3 class="recipe-title-item">Helllllllo</h3>
                    <a href="#" class="blog__button">
                        More details <i class='uil uil-angle-right-b blog__icon'></i> 
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="recipe__card mix">
                    <img src="./asset/img/burrito_recipe.jpeg" alt="" class="recipe__img">
                    <h3 class="recipe-title-item">aelllllllo</h3>
                    <a href="#" class="blog__button">
                        More details <i class='uil uil-angle-right-b blog__icon'></i> 
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="recipe__card mix">
                    <img src="./asset/img/pasta_recipe.jpeg" alt="" class="recipe__img">
                    <h3 class="recipe-title-item">Telllllllo</h3>
                    <a href="#" class="blog__button">
                        More details <i class='uil uil-angle-right-b blog__icon'></i> 
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="recipe__card mix burgersandwiches">
                    <img src="./asset/img/burger_recipe.jpeg" alt="" class="recipe__img">
                    <h3 class="recipe-title-item">Telllllllo</h3>
                    <a href="#" class="blog__button">
                        More details <i class='uil uil-angle-right-b blog__icon'></i> 
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="recipe__card mix">
                    <img src="./asset/img/chips_recipe.jpeg" alt="" class="recipe__img">
                    <h3 class="recipe-title-item">Telllllllo</h3>
                    <a href="#" class="blog__button">
                        More details <i class='uil uil-angle-right-b blog__icon'></i> 
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="recipe__card mix ">
                    <img src="./asset/img/raspberry_brownies_recipe.jpeg" alt="" class="recipe__img">
                    <h3 class="recipe-title-item">Telllllllo</h3>
                    <a href="#" class="blog__button">
                        More details <i class='uil uil-angle-right-b blog__icon'></i> 
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="recipe__card mix ">
                    <img src="./asset/img/steaks_recipe.jpeg" alt="" class="recipe__img">
                    <h3 class="recipe-title-item">Zelllllllo</h3>
                    <a href="#" class="blog__button">
                        More details <i class='uil uil-angle-right-b blog__icon'></i> 
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="recipe__card mix ">
                    <img src="./asset/img/shrimp_pasta_recipe.jpeg" alt="" class="recipe__img">
                    <h3 class="recipe-title-item">Telllllllo</h3>
                    <a href="#" class="blog__button">
                        More details <i class='uil uil-angle-right-b blog__icon'></i> 
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="recipe__card mix ">
                    <img src="./asset/img/ribs_recipe.jpeg" alt="" class="recipe__img">
                    <h3 class="recipe-title-item">Ribs</h3>
                    <a href="#" class="blog__button">
                        More details <i class='uil uil-angle-right-b blog__icon'></i> 
                    </a>
                </div>

        </section>
```

All I added is the following condition inside the for-loop: `input != ""`

If the input is blank, the program will jump to the `else` statement which hides the recipeCards.

Comment: this is not a good practice , you're actually doing a double check here , put the empty input check before the loop

Comment: you have to put a separate loop, in both cases you will run a loop
but if you separate it you can avoid the below check
recipeCard[i].textContent.toLowerCase().includes(input)

Comment: @KSRdev Hi, I edited my solution. I believe my solution now is better practice and more efficient than the accepted solution as I only added a single condition without all the code repetition. Check it out

Comment: Hi @15Rabi you're right this one is better thanks, its my first time that i post a question here, now everything works.

Answer (score 0):

I added your code into a snippet, so I added a condition that checks if input's value is empty, if so, it would make all elements hidden, if not, it executes your code.

```js
function search_recipe() {
    let input = document.getElementById('search').value
    input = input.toLowerCase();
    let recipeCard = document.getElementsByClassName('recipe__card');
    if(input === ""){
      for (i = 0; i < recipeCard.length; i++) {
        recipeCard[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
    else {
      for (i = 0; i < recipeCard.length; i++) {
        if (recipeCard[i].textContent.toLowerCase().includes(input)) {
            recipeCard[i].style.display = "block";
        }
        else {
            recipeCard[i].style.display = "none";

        }
    }
    }
    
}
```

```css
.recipe__container {
    padding-top: 1rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 3rem;
}

.recipe__filters {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    column-gap: .75rem;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.recipe__item {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: var(--title-color);
    padding: .25rem .75rem;
    font-weight: var(--font-medium);
    border-radius: .5rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.recipe__items {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: var(--title-color);
    font-weight: var(--font-medium);
    border-radius: .5rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.recipe__card {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 32px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37);
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    display: none;
}

.recipe__img {
    border-radius: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: var(--mb-1-25);
    width: 230px;
}

.recipe-title-item {
    font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
    font-weight: var(--font-medium);
    margin-bottom: var(--mb-0-75);
}

.hide_categories {
    display: none;
    transition: all ease-in-out;
}

.categories {
    display: grid;
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
    transition: all ease-in-out;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, max-content);
}

#categories-button {
    z-index: 9;
}

.cat {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

#categories-button {
    margin-left: 1rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.active-recipe {
    background-color: var(--first-color);
    color: var(--white-color);
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
textarea[type="text"],
select {
    padding-left: 1rem;
}

.recipe {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<section class="recipe section" id="work">
            <h2 class="section__title">Recipe</h2>
            <div class="recipe__filters">
                <input type="text" onkeyup="search_recipe()" placeholder="search" id="search" class="section__search"></input>
                <div class="cat">
                    <h3>Categories</h3>
                    <i class="uil uil-arrow-right" id="categories-button"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="hide_categories" id="h_categories">
                    <span class="all recipe__item active-recipe " data-filter='all'>All </span>
                    <span class="recipe__item" data-filter='.breakfast'>Breakfast</span>
                    <span class="recipe__item" data-filter='.dessert'>dessert</span>
                    <span class="recipe__item" data-filter='.burgersandwiches'>Burger & Sandwiches</span>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="recipe__container container">
                <!-- <div class="recipe__card mix ">
                    <img src="./asset/img" alt="" class="recipe__img">
                    <h3 class="recipe-title-item"></h3>
                    <a href="#" class="recipe__button">
                        More details <i class='uil uil-angle-right-b recipe__icon'></i> 
                    </a>
                </div> -->
                <div class="recipe__card mix">
                    <img src="./asset/img/ramen_recipe.jpeg" alt="" class="recipe__img">
                    <h3 class="recipe-title-item">Helllllllo</h3>
                    <a href="#" class="blog__button">
                        More details <i class='uil uil-angle-right-b blog__icon'></i> 
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="recipe__card mix">
                    <img src="./asset/img/burrito_recipe.jpeg" alt="" class="recipe__img">
                    <h3 class="recipe-title-item">aelllllllo</h3>
                    <a href="#" class="blog__button">
                        More details <i class='uil uil-angle-right-b blog__icon'></i> 
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="recipe__card mix">
                    <img src="./asset/img/pasta_recipe.jpeg" alt="" class="recipe__img">
                    <h3 class="recipe-title-item">Telllllllo</h3>
                    <a href="#" class="blog__button">
                        More details <i class='uil uil-angle-right-b blog__icon'></i> 
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="recipe__card mix burgersandwiches">
                    <img src="./asset/img/burger_recipe.jpeg" alt="" class="recipe__img">
                    <h3 class="recipe-title-item">Telllllllo</h3>
                    <a href="#" class="blog__button">
                        More details <i class='uil uil-angle-right-b blog__icon'></i> 
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="recipe__card mix">
                    <img src="./asset/img/chips_recipe.jpeg" alt="" class="recipe__img">
                    <h3 class="recipe-title-item">Telllllllo</h3>
                    <a href="#" class="blog__button">
                        More details <i class='uil uil-angle-right-b blog__icon'></i> 
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="recipe__card mix ">
                    <img src="./asset/img/raspberry_brownies_recipe.jpeg" alt="" class="recipe__img">
                    <h3 class="recipe-title-item">Telllllllo</h3>
                    <a href="#" class="blog__button">
                        More details <i class='uil uil-angle-right-b blog__icon'></i> 
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="recipe__card mix ">
                    <img src="./asset/img/steaks_recipe.jpeg" alt="" class="recipe__img">
                    <h3 class="recipe-title-item">Zelllllllo</h3>
                    <a href="#" class="blog__button">
                        More details <i class='uil uil-angle-right-b blog__icon'></i> 
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="recipe__card mix ">
                    <img src="./asset/img/shrimp_pasta_recipe.jpeg" alt="" class="recipe__img">
                    <h3 class="recipe-title-item">Telllllllo</h3>
                    <a href="#" class="blog__button">
                        More details <i class='uil uil-angle-right-b blog__icon'></i> 
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="recipe__card mix ">
                    <img src="./asset/img/ribs_recipe.jpeg" alt="" class="recipe__img">
                    <h3 class="recipe-title-item">Ribs</h3>
                    <a href="#" class="blog__button">
                        More details <i class='uil uil-angle-right-b blog__icon'></i> 
                    </a>
                </div>

        </section>
```